# Jquery links stop working after dialog is open

Tags: jquery

I'm hoping all of you experts in jquery can help me out with this.
I have a chatroom in html/jquery.
I have a DIV with a dynamic list of users that gets refreshed everytime a new user comes in the chatroom.
When you click on any of the users, a jquery dialog appears for private chat.
That all works fine. The problem is after the first private chat (jquery dialog) is opened, if a new user comes in the chatroom, the links for chatroom users don't work anymore. (even if a try refreshing the users-list).
I checked with developer console in mozilla and see that when the dialog is opened a DIV section is added to the end of the html page.
That's when all the other jquery generated links stop working.

Here is the functions in question (works ok for any number of users, until the first private chat dialog is open, after that the links stop working):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 


    function privateChatLoader() {

        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#chatRoomUsers td a').each(function() {
                var chatRoomId = $.trim($('#chatRoomId').val());
                var fromUsername = $.trim($('#username').val());
                var privateMessageTop = '<tr><td align="left" valign="middle" class="popup-box-top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td width="10">&nbsp;</td><td width="300" align="left" valign="middle"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td width="23" align="left" valign="middle"><img src="images/icon-popup.png" width="16" height="16" /></td><td align="left" valign="middle" class="popup-title-text ">_TO_USERNAME_</td></tr></table></td><td align="right" valign="middle"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td><td width="18" align="right" valign="middle"><a href="#" onClick="closePrivateMessage();" id="dialog2"><img src="images/button-close.png" width="15" height="14" border="0" /></a></td></tr></table></td><td width="10">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr>';
                var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
                var $link = $(this).on('click', function() {
                    var toUsername = $link.attr("id");
                    privateMessageTop = privateMessageTop.replace("_TO_USERNAME_", toUsername);
                    $dialog
                        .load('privatemessage.php?cid=' + chatRoomId + '&s=' + fromUsername + '&r=' + toUsername)
                        .dialog({
                            //autoOpen: false,
                            title: privateMessageTop,
                            close: toUsername,
                            width: 400,
                            height: 300
                        });

                    $link.click(function() {
                        $dialog.dialog('open');
                        return false;
                    });

                    return false;
                });
            });
    });
}
```

****UPDATE:****
Nevermind. I got it working. 
The issue was that in the page I was loading in the dialog, I was also loading all my javascript, and jquery files again (from copy and paste from main page).
Once I removed all that from that page, everything works as intended.
Thanks guys

Comment: A little more info:
I call the function above anytime a new user enters the chatroom to refresh the links to the chatRoomUsers and that works fine.

The only time it doesn't work is after a dialog has opened. Even if I call this method to refresh the links.
I've tried on, delegate, bind -- no difference.

Comment: not enough code shown, such as `toUsername` to know what is happening. A link would help

Comment: just noticed you have a click handler being called inside a click handler for same element

Comment: Charlie, thanks for looking into this.

I don't have this yet on any public webserver to provide a link, but heres a bit more info:

The toUsername just contains the name of user clicked.
It's generated by replacing the _TOUSERNAME_ from a request value:

<a href='#' id='_TOUSERNAME_'>&nbsp;_USERNAME_</a>

That link is inside a table and that's how it works for the .each in the function.

The dialog just opens a test html page with "test" in the body tag.

Again, it all works ok (the links for each new chat user) until a dialog is open. After that, but the links don't work anymore

Comment: I'm not that good with jquery, but the issue is that as long as no div is added to the end of the html (when opening the dialog), the function properly refreshes all the links. But if I click on any chatUser on the list (and the div for the dialog is added to the bottom of doc), calling that function and trying to refresh the links doesn't work anymore

Answer (score 0):

It is important to understand that when you replace html with same elements, you lose the events that were bound directly to them. The same applies to adding new elements that weren't in the page when original event handlers were applied.

It is hard to tell exactly which part of your code is the problem without seeing the other code and how your UI works.

It can be seen however that you are ajax loading content and therefore you should learn how to delegate events so that future elements will automatically have those events attached.

If you are using jQuery 1.7 you will want to use `on()`, if lesser version use `delegate()`

For a detailed explanation: [jQUery Docs FAQ - Why events stop working after Ajax request](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Why_do_my_events_stop_working_after_an_AJAX_request.3F)

Methods API links:

http://api.jquery.com/on/

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Comment: Thanks, but I tried using both on and delegate and still works the same way.

Comment: you may not be implementing them properly, must delegate to either document, or a permanent element, and use the selector argument
`$(document).on('click', 'yourLinkSelector', function(){...`

Answer (score 0):

Your use of .dialog doesn't look quite right to me.

Try this:

```
function privateChatLoader() {

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#chatRoomUsers td a').each(function() {
            var chatRoomId = $.trim($('#chatRoomId').val());
            var fromUsername = $.trim($('#username').val());
            var privateMessageTop = '<tr><td align="left" valign="middle" class="popup-box-top"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td width="10">&nbsp;</td><td width="300" align="left" valign="middle"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td width="23" align="left" valign="middle"><img src="images/icon-popup.png" width="16" height="16" /></td><td align="left" valign="middle" class="popup-title-text ">_TO_USERNAME_</td></tr></table></td><td align="right" valign="middle"><table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td align="right" valign="middle">&nbsp;</td><td width="18" align="right" valign="middle"><a href="#" onClick="closePrivateMessage();" id="dialog2"><img src="images/button-close.png" width="15" height="14" border="0" /></a></td></tr></table></td><td width="10">&nbsp;</td></tr></table></td></tr>';
            var $dialog = $('<div></div>')
            var toUsername = $(this).attr("id");
            privateMessageTop = privateMessageTop.replace("_TO_USERNAME_", toUsername);

            $dialog.load('privatemessage.php?cid=' + chatRoomId + '&s=' + fromUsername + '&r=' + toUsername)
                   .dialog({
                        autoOpen: false,
                        title: privateMessageTop,
                        close: toUsername,
                        width: 400,
                        height: 300
                    });

            $(this).click(function() {
                 $dialog.dialog('open');
                 return false;
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Then make sure you are using

```
.dialog('close')
```

to close the dialog box.

For more details see this blog: http://blog.nemikor.com/2009/04/08/basic-usage-of-the-jquery-ui-dialog/

Comment: Thanks, but I tried your method and still same error, doesn't make a difference.